# replace source.list causes docker image starts fail

Tags: docker

I have a base image including Tomcat 7, which stays in RAM and listen to the port correctly after I run `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d` it as a container.

Then I want to change the /etc/apt/source.list. So I first run the base image manually and open an bash. Then I used `docker cp source.list #baseHash:/etc/apt/` command to copy my preferred source.list to the image. After that I did `docker tag` and `docker commit` the modified image as "modsource" image.

How the weird thing is that, after I issue docker-compose commands, the container (using modsource) simply quite with status "Exit(0)". All I did was just changing the /etc/apt/source.list.

I studied the image, and believe it runs `/app-entrypoint.sh` after the container starts. The script code is:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

. /opt/bitnami/base/functions
. /opt/bitnami/base/helpers

print_welcome_page

if [[ "$1" == "nami" && "$2" == "start" ]] || [[ "$1" == "/init.sh" ]]; then
  nami_initialize tomcat
  info "Starting tomcat... "
fi

exec tini -- "$@"
```

When I run the modsource image, from the `docker log`, I only see the welcome page messages. I don't see any tomcat initialization messages. However, with the base image, I see a whole lot of running messages after the welcome message. So I guess with the "modsource" image, the `if` statement in the script just does not pass.

After that investigation, I ran `dock image history` on both images and diff the results. Here it's:

```
╰─➤  diff base.his modsource.his                                                                           [04/26/20 % 4:41PM]
2c2,3
< 4f657f0ee5af        8 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["nami" "start" "--fo…   0B
---
> 68b8feb75b3b        25 hours ago        /bin/bash                                       361B
> <missing>           8 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["nami" "start" "--fo…   0B
```

68b8feb75b3b is the container ID of the container run from modsource image. The command "nami" "start" is still there in the modsource image. Somehow it does not run...

So my question here is why my operation of copying source.list causing problem? What's the right approach to implement the change I want to the image?

Comment: You should avoid `docker commit` if at all possible.  Can you restructure this in the form of a `Dockerfile` and a `docker build` command; and does this solve the "lost CMD" problem?  (Say there's a new release of Tomcat with a critical security fix in a year; will you remember how to recreate your manual APT configuration change?)

Comment: I think you are right about the Dockerfile. I actually coded another Dockerfile to create the image instead of using "docker commit". It seems it's working fine now.